# Looking at internal Methods

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to see the function that's used when I use str(), as I'd like to modify it a bit for my own purposes as another function.

When I type `str()`, I get the following:

```
function (object, ...) 
UseMethod("str")
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

So I tried, `getAnywhere(str)`:

```
2 differing objects matching ‘str’ were found
in the following places
  .GlobalEnv
  package:utils
  namespace:utils
Use [] to view one of them
```

But there's nothing in the documentation about what the syntax should be for using `[]`

So I tried, `getAnywhere(str)[1]`:

```
function (object, ...) 
UseMethod("str")
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

Sigh. Allright, what about `showMethods(str)`:

```
Function "str":
 <not a generic function>
```

So, how do I see the construction of the output for `str()`? Or can I?

Comment: You must have a local `str` object created as when I do this is a clean session `getAnywhere(str)` finds only the function in `utils`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `methods()` for an S3 generic such as `str()`:

```
> methods(str)
[1] str.data.frame* str.Date*       str.default*   
[4] str.dendrogram* str.logLik*     str.POSIXt*    

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Using `getAnywhere(str)` is not really helpful because `str()` is visible so you get the same result if you just run `str` at the prompt. You need `getAnywhere()` to look at the hidden methods listed above:

```
getAnywhere(str.default)
```

for example.

Shame you need to know what kind of generic a function is to list the methods; seems user-friendliness would be improved if R didn't care what kind of method type was supplied to one or other of these functions.

Answer (score 8):

You could also do it like this:

```
> methods(by)
[1] by.data.frame by.default
> getS3method("by", "data.frame")
function (data, INDICES, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE) 
{
   ...
}
<environment: namespace:base>
```