# What does useMethod mean here?

Tags: r, xts

One of the kool things about R is if I type the function name I get to see the implementation. But this one is confusing me, recursively:

```
> library(xts)
> align.time
function (x, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("align.time")
}
<environment: namespace:xts>
```

x is an XTS object, so doesn't that mean it will call the XTS align.time method... but that is what I'm looking at! (Typing `xts::align.time` gives exactly the same response.)

Comment: See also this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5835312/602276

Comment: Circle 7 of http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf might help you get a sense of what generic functions and methods are all about.

Comment: @PatrickBurns Thanks, that looks like a useful read.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, all very helpful (I gave the tick to Andrie as he needs the points more than Gavin ;-). I'll try and remember methods() and triple colons next time I get stuck.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The short answer is that you are looking for the function `xts:::align.time.xts`.

The longer answer is that you can find which methods exist for `align.time` by calling `methods`:

```
> methods(align.time)
[1] align.time.POSIXct* align.time.POSIXlt* align.time.xts*    

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

This tells you that there is a method `align.time.xts` that is not exported from the namespace.  At this point you can probably guess that it can be found in package `xts`, but you can confirm that with `getAnywhere`:

```
> getAnywhere("align.time.xts")
A single object matching 'align.time.xts' was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for align.time from namespace xts
  namespace:xts
with value

function (x, n = 60, ...) 
{
    if (n <= 0) 
        stop("'n' must be positive")
    .xts(x, .index(x) + (n - .index(x)%%n), tzone = indexTZ(x), 
        tclass = indexClass(x))
}
<environment: namespace:xts>
```

---

You can, of course, read the source directly, but since the function is not exported, you need to use `package:::function` (i.e. three colons):

```
> xts:::align.time.xts
function (x, n = 60, ...) 
{
    if (n <= 0) 
        stop("'n' must be positive")
    .xts(x, .index(x) + (n - .index(x)%%n), tzone = indexTZ(x), 
        tclass = indexClass(x))
}
<environment: namespace:xts>
```

Answer (score 8):

`align.time()` is exported from the **xts** namespace, so `xts::align.time` and `align.time` are the same thing. You need to note that there is an `align.time()` method for objects of class `"xts"` provided in the package and that is not exported from the namespace (it is just registered as an S3 method):

```
> xts:::align.time.xts
function (x, n = 60, ...) 
{
    if (n <= 0) 
        stop("'n' must be positive")
    .xts(x, .index(x) + (n - .index(x)%%n), tzone = indexTZ(x), 
        tclass = indexClass(x))
}
<environment: namespace:xts>
```

It is this method that is being called when you pass an `"xts"` object to `align.time()`.

When you call `align.time()` `UseMethod()` sets up the search for and call of the appropriate `"align.time"` method, if available, for the class of object supplied as the first argument. `UseMethod` is doing exactly what you think it is doing, you have just confused yourself by looking at the same function (the generic) in two different ways.

Comment: :-) right back at you. The OP should also take into account the first derivative of our respective rep profiles when deciding on awarding the accept. You're motoring ahead of late! ;-)