# Find the used method for R wrapper functions

Tags: r

I am Looking at this Question: [What does useMethod mean here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267181/what-does-usemethod-mean-here).

I am trying to do the same for XML::read_xml

```
read_xml
(ms <- methods("read_xml"))
```

Output is:

```
[1] read_xml.character*  read_xml.connection*
[3] read_xml.raw*        read_xml.response*
```

How do i know which of the four to take? And more importantly how does the call `use_methods("read_xml")` decides?

Comment: thank you for the proposed edit. The Question doesnt restrict to the read_xml function, one could ask a similar Question to the Code in the linked Question. So if someone has a similar Question but for a different function, it might be easier to find,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to take any of the four. When you call on `read_xml`, the function looks at the class of the first argument (x, in this case) (e.g., a character string, a connection), and calls the function for that class. Basically, when you do `read_xml(x)`, the function calls `read_xml.[class(x)](x)`.

If the argument has more than one class, `UseMethods` will cycle through all the classes, from first to last, until if finds one with a method. Some functions might also have a `default` method, which is used if no other, more specific method, is found. `read_xml`, as you can see, doesn't have one. If you try using `read_xml` with a first argument that is, say, numeric, you'll get this error from `UseMethod`:

```
Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

As noted in the question you linked to, you can see the code for the specific class functions by using `getAnywhere`.