# How to look at the implementation of this function?

Tags: r, internal

I want to see, how sctest of the strucchange package is implemented.

I install and load the package:

```
install.packages("strucchange")
library(strucchange)
```

Now I want to look at the implementation and I do:

```
sctest
```

But this gives only

```
> sctest
function (x, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("sctest")
}
<environment: namespace:strucchange>
```

So I tried `getAnywhere(sctest)`, but this does also not help me. So how can I look at the code?

I looked at [Looking at internal Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835312/looking-at-internal-methods) and the R Inferno.

EDIT: I tried

```
 methods(sctest)
```

this gives me

```
[1] sctest.efp*     sctest.formula* sctest.Fstats*  sctest.gefp*   

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Now I can use getAnywhere() but which of these functions is the right one for me?

Comment: Use `getAnywhere` with the suffix you need, eg. `getAnywhere( sctest.efp )` the method depends on the object you are passing to `sctest`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking at internal Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835312/looking-at-internal-methods),  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579100/how-to-view-r-source-code/15579274#15579274 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371928/view-the-source-of-an-builtin-r-package/11372006#11372006